# How to execute a Powershell cmdlet as a specific user and save the return value in a variable?

Tags: powershell

How can I execute a Powershell cmdlet as a specific user and save the return value in a variable?

What I got so far is this snippet

```
Start-Process powershell.exe -Credential $credentials -NoNewWindow -ArgumentList "Get-Item Env:AppData"
```

The problem is that any return values live only withing the process and are not brought to the powershell environment from where I executed said command.

Comment: What do you mean with "return value" ? e.g : `C:\Users\chris\AppData\Roaming` or return status True/False ?

Comment: Yes, "C:\Users\chris\AppData\Roaming". However, not as a string, but as a Powershell object. Same asvariable profile in "$profile = Get-Item Env:AppData".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Invoke-Command` with specified credentials and then `return` the value from the invoked ScriptBlock:

```
$Credentials = (Get-Credential)
$ScriptToExecute = {return (Get-Item Env:AppData)}
$AppData = Invoke-Command -ComputerName localhost -Credential $Credentials -ScriptBlock $ScriptToExecute

$AppData # Now contains the Environment var named "AppData"
```

If this throws any errors, you need to execute `winrm quickconfig`. If it still fails, run powershell.exe with admin privileges.